# SEO перелинковка между сайтами

Tags: seo

**Подскажите пожалуйста:**
Пришло предложение по перелинковке с трастового ресурса.
Условия хорошие. Они предлагают написать о нас лонгрид в блоге (более 2.3 млн. бэклинков у домена, траст большой)
Со своей стороны мы делаем dofollow ссылку на эту же страницу их блога, со своей главной.
Объясните пожалуйста, почему это им может быть полезно?
Линк не на "морду" сайта, а на страницу блога 3го уровня структуры!
Это я чего не понимаю, или **действительно правильно для перелинковки**?!

Comment: Уточните, они ставят на вас ссылку с лонгрида, который третьего уровня вложенности? Какой индекс качества у Вашего сайта?

Comment: @ИванКонкин да, dofollow ссылка с лонгрида, третьего уровня.
Наш ИКС = 90 по Яндексу, сайту чуть более 3 мес.
Наш DR = 18 по Ahref и 97 бэклинков от 17 доноров.

При этом их DR (главной страницы) = 76 и 2.3М бэклинков от 14К доноров.
Вес огромный, поэтому и возникает вопрос: Какая им в этом выгода?

Comment: Ссылаясь с третьего уровня вложенности, они передают вес ссылки на много меньше, чем получают от Вас с главной. Таким образом, если построить сеть из таких сайтов, то можно получить хорошее ссылочное продвижение.